# Configure full screen backend module for typo3 custom extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I am new to typo3 extension development, i have created extension with extension_builder as well as backend module too.

**ext_tables.php**

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {

        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
            'USER.Webuser',
            'web', // Make module a submodule of 'web'
            'bewebuser', // Submodule key
            '', // Position
            [
                'Users' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
            ],
            [
                'access' => 'user,group',
                'icon'   => 'EXT:' . $extKey . '/Resources/Public/Icons/user_mod_bewebuser.svg',
                'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $extKey . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_bewebuser.xlf',
            ]
        );

    }
```

Typoscript :

```
# Setting up template
module.tx_webuser_web_webuserbewebuser {
    persistence {
       storagePid = {$module.tx_webuser_bewebuser.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    view {
        templateRootPaths = EXT:webuser/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
        partialRootPaths = EXT:webuser/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
        layoutRootPaths = EXT:webuser/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
    }
}
```

Its working file. here is my BE module:
[image]

But, i want to create full area including page tree. Can anyone tell me how to remove page tree for my custom extension use? I want to use entire area for my custom extension.

Thanks an advance!

Comment: Do you mean a backend modul without pagetree column?

Comment: Yes, exactly.. @jokumer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After taking a look [into the source](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-7-1/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Utility/ExtensionUtility.php#L182-L185), it seems you can add the option `'navigationComponentId' => '',` to the last argument of registerModule to get what you want.

*Edit: 2021-02-10.* For TYPO3 10 you need to additionally add `'inheritNavigationComponentFromMainModule' => false` to the list. I'd assume that only applies if the main module (web in this case) has the page tree activated.

In your example it would be:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
    'USER.Webuser',
    'web', // Make module a submodule of 'web'
    'bewebuser', // Submodule key
    '', // Position
    [
        'Users' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    ],
    [
        'access' => 'user,group',
        'icon'   => 'EXT:' . $extKey . '/Resources/Public/Icons/user_mod_bewebuser.svg',
        'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $extKey . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_bewebuser.xlf',
        'navigationComponentId' => '',
        'inheritNavigationComponentFromMainModule' => false,
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @Nitori,but i have already tried this before. Its still showing page tree module..

Comment: Have you reloaded your backend and cleared all caches? It worked for me both in TYPO3 7.6 and 8.7

Comment: Oh yes Its works ! I need to reload hole page. Thank you very much..!

Comment: I already asked myself this question a thousand times. Finally I've got an answer to this question of life. Thank you... now I finally can rest in peace.

Comment: Since TYPO3 9 LTS you also have to add `'inheritNavigationComponentFromMainModule' => false` to the array above to hide the page tree.